# Nativescript with Angular - usesCleartextTraffic="true" flag in application tag not working in Emulator

Tags: android, angular, http, nativescript

I cannot get rid of **Cleartext HTTP traffic** error in my Nativescript application. I saw all the relevant threads and added the following configuration to my app:

In AndroidManifest.xml added:

```
<application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

Also added the following file in to two locations:
 **App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml**
**App_Resources/Android/xml/network_security_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

And the error:

{"originalStack":"Error: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com not permitted\n    at new ZoneAwareError (file:///data/data/com.app.app/files/app/vendor.js:92106:33)\n    at onRequestComplete (file:///data/data/com.app.app/files/app/vendor.js:131598:34)\n    at Object.onComplete (file:///data/data/com.app.app/files/app/vendor.js:131587:13)","zoneAwareStack":"Error: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com not permitted\n    at onRequestComplete (file:///data/data/com.app.app/files/app/vendor.js:131598:34) []\n    at Object.onComplete file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\http\http-request\http-request.js:43:0

**Running on Android Emulator-Pixel_2_API_28:5554**

**UPDATE:**
    It works on real device.

Comment: Are you sure you tried a clean build? Which version of Android you are testing with?

Comment: Yep. Few times removed "node_modules" and "platforms" folders while trying various configurations. The emulator runs Android 9.